# Return largest number from nested arrays without math.max

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to return the largest number from each subarray to a new array.  I feel like I'm really close, and I feel like `if(temp[j] < x) {continue;}` is out of place.  What am I doing wrong?  P.S. I know I can probably just use math.max() and save a lot of code, but i'm trying to get comfortable with for loops and arrays.

```
  function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let newArr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let temp = arr[i];
    let counter = 0;
    for(let j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
      let x = 0;
      if(temp[j] > counter) {
      counter = temp[j];
      if(counter > x) {
        x = counter;
        if(temp[j] < x) {
          continue;
        }
      }
      newArr.push(temp[j]);

      }

    }
    console.log(arr[i])
  }
  console.log(newArr);
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well (which direction?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you expecting an output of `[5, 27, 39, 1001]`?

If so, these minor adjustments to your inner loop will do the job:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    let newArr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let temp = arr[i];
        let x = 0;
        for(let j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {

            if(temp[j] > x) {
                x = temp[j];
            }
        }

        newArr.push(x);
        //console.log(arr[i])
    }
    console.log(newArr);
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

You were on the right track, but you want to avoid pushing the highest value for the sub-array on to `newArr` until the inner loop has finished iterating over that sub-array. Until it's done iterating, you don't know which value is the highest for the sub-array.

Comment: would have failed my interview, what if the max number is not greater than zero? Initialization should be based off first index, not 0.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  This is what my answer looked like, before i tried adding in if(counter > x) {
        x = counter;
        if(temp[j] < x) {
          continue;

Comment: @epascarello  This was my original strategy, i'll be sure to go with this in the future, thanks for your input.

Comment: @epascarello I am assuming the data set is positive whole numbers. I am also assuming that the parent array only contains arrays, and those child arrays only contain numbers, not strings, objects, etc. The point here is to help the OP make the next small improvement in his code, understand what he was doing wrong, and to learn. The point of my answer is not to catch every single possible edge case or completely re-write his code with something more efficient/elegant.

Answer (score 2):

@Elliot B.'s answer is probably what you are looking for as explaination of what went wrong where.

Alternate solution using Map/Reduce on Array

Solution taken from here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/three-ways-to-return-largest-numbers-in-arrays-in-javascript-5d977baa80a1

```js
function largestOfFour(mainArray) {
  return mainArray.map(function (subArray){
    return subArray.reduce(function (previousLargestNumber, currentLargestNumber) {
      return (currentLargestNumber > previousLargestNumber) ? currentLargestNumber : previousLargestNumber;
    }, 0);
  });
}
//largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);


const result = largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It would be better to omit the initializer ("0") to make it work with negative numbers.

Comment: Yeah by default it should take `0` as value if not provided

Comment: nope, if you don't provide the init value, reduce takes the first elem as init and starts with the second.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you need to get the largest number in the inner loop, and then push it:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let newArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let temp = arr[i];
    let res = -Infinity; // initialize the res with lowest number
    for (let j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
      if (temp[j] > res) { // if a number is greater than res, assign it to res
        res = temp[j];
      }
    }
    newArr.push(res); // push res to the result arr
  }
  return newArr;
}

const result = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(result);
```

It would be easier if you'll refactor the maximum logic to an external function:

```js
const getArrayMax = ([first, ...arr]) => {
  let mx = first;
  
  for (const cur of arr)
    if (cur > mx)
      mx = cur;
  
  return mx;
}

function largestOfSubarrays(arr) {
  const newArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(getArrayMax(arr[i])); // push res to the result arr
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

const result = largestOfSubarrays([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I didn't realize that this was a FCC basic algorithm challenge (the section i happen to be at), so I tried my solution, and it didn't work for -1.  Your strategy of initializing to -Infinity makes sense now, Thanks!

Comment: You could simply initialize with `temp[0]` and start looping from 1.

Comment: @georg That was what I originally did, but it just didn't look right to me haha.

Comment: And this plays nicely with refactoring to two functions, and destructuring. See updated 2nd answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply sort the arrays in `desc` order and get the first element:

```js
const largestOfFour = arr => arr.map(x => x.sort((a,b) => b-a)[0])

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]))
```